# Increased runtime for the second loop?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have encountered a problem recently, please help me:

My program needs to process a lot of data, but the memory is not enough, so data is divided into ten parts and used loop. After each loop, use `.backward()` to clear the dynamic graph, and then go to the next loop. The first loop took 0.5s, but every subsequent loop took 1.5s. I output the running time of each step and found that the first line of code in the loop always takes 1s. Swap the order of the codes. After the swap, the code in the first line takes 1s, and the original code in the first line does not take 1s.

I set breakpoints in the loop to debug the code. After the first loop runs, if I wait a second or two before running the next loop, the time will not increase by 1s.

Is it possible that cleaning up the video memory or the dynamic graph increases time. Please help me , thank you!

Comment: you gotta help us help you. If you would include some sort of example that would go a long way

Comment: What is most likely slowing you down is garbage collection.  I am sure that all of those optimization tweaks could help but it's unlikely to be a significantly noticeable difference.

Comment: Where is your CODE?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.